# Can't configure email and reset password on Ghost blog

Tags: linux, email, configuration, ghost-blog

I have a Ghost blog and I forgot my password(yes). I tried typing it 5 times and now my account is blocked.

I want to reset the password but, for some reason I don't understand, Ghost(or my server, I don't know) is not able to send me e-mail.

I followed the steps described here http://support.ghost.org/mail to set up my e-mail account from gmail on the server. My config.js file is like this:

````
// # Ghost Configuration
// Setup your Ghost install for various environments
// Documentation can be found at http://support.ghost.org/config/

var path = require('path'),
    config;

config = {
    // ### Production
    // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment
    // Configure your URL and mail settings here
    production: {
        url: 'http://gabsferreira.com',
        mail: {
              transport: 'SMTP',
              options: {
                  service: 'Gmail',
                  auth: {
                      user: 'myuser', 
                      pass: 'mypass'  
                  }
               }
          },

        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },

        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '2368'
        }
   },

    // ### Development **(default)**
  development: {
        // The url to use when providing links to the site, E.g. in RSS and email.
        // Change this to your Ghost blogs published URL.
        url: 'http://gabsferreira.com',

        // Example mail config
        // Visit http://support.ghost.org/mail for instructions


        mail: {
              transport: 'SMTP',
              options: {
                  service: 'Gmail',
                  auth: {
                      user: 'myuser', // mailgun username
                      pass: 'mypass'  // mailgun password
                  }
               }
          },
        // ```



        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '2368'
        },
        paths: {
            contentPath: path.join(__dirname, '/content/')



    },

    // **Developers only need to edit below here**

    // ### Testing
    // Used when developing Ghost to run tests and check the health of Ghost
    // Uses a different port number
    testing: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-test.db')
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
        },
      logging: false
    },

    // ### Testing MySQL
    // Used by Travis - Automated testing run through GitHub
    'testing-mysql': {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'mysql',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'root',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_testing',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: '2369'
     },
        logging: false
    },

    // ### Testing pg
    // Used by Travis - Automated testing run through GitHub
    'testing-pg': {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2369',
        database: {
            client: 'pg',
            connection: {
                host     : '127.0.0.1',
                user     : 'postgres',
                password : '',
                database : 'ghost_testing',
                charset  : 'utf8'
            }
        },
        server: {
            host: '127.0.0.1',
     port: '2369'
        },
        logging: false
    }
};

// Export config
module.exports = config;
````

In "myuser" and "mypass" are my user and password, typed correctly.

When I try to reset the password, I get this error message:

[image]

I don't know what to do, because I don't know what's wrong. Do I need to enable something on gmail? Is there a place where ghost is logging the error that's happening?

I'm not a heavy Ubuntu user, so I'm not sure where to look or what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article has pretty clear steps on how to reset it from the sqlite http://sharadchhetri.com/2015/06/07/ghost-blog-reset-password-and-activate-user-from-sqlite/

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me (: